# Tapestry - Composite components?

Tags: java, tapestry

can somebody tell me how to create composite components in Tapestry?
I know how to do this in JSF with using  as well as ui:define.
But how with tapestry?

I'd like to create following setup:

`sidebar.tml`: should define some replaceable variables, here 'header' and 'content'

```
<t:container>
The header is ${header}, and the content ist ${content}.
</t:container>
```

`layout.tml`: should define the right place for the sidebar to always align to

```
//header
<t:sidebar /> 
//footer
```

`customPage.tml`: should deliver the content for the sidebar

```
<t:sidebar>
    <t:header>my header</t:header>
    <t:content>some content here</t:content>
</t:sidebar>
```

I know is cannot be done this way, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to do and could help me?

tyvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

sidebar.tml

```
<t:container>
The header is <t:delegate to="header"/>, and the content ist <t:delegate to="content"/>
</t:container>
```

Sidebar.java

```
public class Sidebar
{
    @Property
    @Parameter(required = true)
    private Block header;

    @Property
    @Parameter(required = true)
    private Block content;
```

layout.tml

```
//header
<t:sidebar header="sidebarHeader" content="sidebarContent"/> 
//footer
```

Layout.java

```
public class Layout
{
    @Property
    @Parameter(required = true)
    private Block sidebarHeader;

    @Property
    @Parameter(required = true)
    private Block sidebarContent;
```

customPage.tml

```
<t:layout>
    <p:sidebarHeader>my header</p:sidebarHeader>
    <p:sidebarContent>some content here</p:sidebarContent>
    rest of your content here
</t:layout>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hm thats quite nice! But I get only String output "sidebarHeader" and "sidebarContent". It is not replaced by the tags in content of customPage.

Comment: It looks like somehow you are using "literal" binding prefix by default. Change your parameters to use the "prop" binding prefix instead. Like this: @Parameter(defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.PROP)